# Android program crashes upon trying to change activities

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I am just beginning Android programming as a college course, and have hit a roadblock.  My program is simply supposed to have a button that switches back and forth between two different activities.  I am writing this in Android Studio.  Here is the code I have currently.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;    

public class ActivityA extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("This is Activity A");
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

No errors occur upon running the program, but it crashes as soon as the button is pressed, rather than moving to the second activity (the second activity is exactly the same, but with any A's and B's switched).
According to the textbook, I am supposed to remove "View." from my OnClickListener, but that just comes up with an error stating that I must use View.OnClickListener.

Comment: Can you add your layout?

Comment: what is the error that shows in Logcat?

Comment: Post your logcat output when the app crashes. Also post the layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add ActivityB to your manifest
your manifest should be something like this

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_a">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityB"></activity>
    </application>
```